# Extracting text of Pdf on windows 8 using python 3.5.0

Tags: python, pdf, information-retrieval, slate

I want to extract texts from Pdf file using python 3.5.0 with the help of slate package on windows8. 
**Problem:** Although I have installed slate package successfully still when i am trying to import slate there are certain errors.Please suggest what i am missing.

Errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       import slate
>     File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\slate-0.4.1-py3.5.egg\slate__init__.py", line 66, in 
>       from slate import PDF
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'PDF'

Answer (score 3):

You could try `pdftotext` ([windows version](http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/)) from the [poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) library.

As a standalone program, it doesn't require Python. But I often use it from Python as a subprocess, like this:

```
import subprocess

args = ['pdftotext', '-layout', '-q', 'input.pdf', '-']
txt = subprocess.check_output(args, universal_newlines=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

slate depends on PDFMiner (Python 3 is not supported.)

You can try to install it with:

```
pip install PDFMiner
```

I went with installing pdfminer3k - [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer3k) - but it did not respond well off the bat (and documentation wasn't good) so I looked a bit more and found this page for [possible alternatives](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167). Let me know if any of these satisfy.

Answer (score 2):

You can install pdfminer.six

```
pip install pdfminer.six
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer.six/20160614